# vite - Subpage with relative asset path

Tags: vue.js, relative-path, vite

I have a Vue project with multiple pages where I use `rollupOptions.input` to specify them as entry points:

```js
rollupOptions: {
    input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        subpage1: resolve(__dirname, "subpage1/index.html"),
        subpage2: resolve(__dirname, "subpage2/index.html")
    }
},
```

The final dist folder will be deployed at a subdirectory in a server,
so I then set a `base` attribute as `base: "",` to make the assets work for the main `index.html` . This turns all the paths into something relative like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/main.35431485.css">`. Works for the root `index.html` but for the subpages, the links look identical. This however doesn't work, because the folder structure is something like:

```
├── index.html
├── assets
    ├── main.35431485.css
    └── ...
└── subpage1
    └── index.html
```

As such, `subpage1/assets/main.35431485.css` will simply not work.
Is there a way to tell vite to relatively path its way to the asset folder, even for subpages?
Ideally not using a static parent directory (like with `base: "/some/dir/"`), but keeping it all relative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that will be [fixed in vite 3.0](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4517). There seems to be a fair amount of issues left for the 3.0 release but hopefully it will be released sometime in 2022. Right now the only way is to have a static base path, changing to some SPA approach, or using another build tool.

Edit: vite 3.0 is now released and relative base path is now properly supported. [See the docs here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path).